# Admob WebFilter log, What does it mean?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm using Google Admob, When I remove testDevice line, I'm getting below logs on the console screen. What does it mean? Is there anything went wrong? Or I need to ignore these lines of logs.

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"_____" ];
WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process _____
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
        filterBlacklist =     (
        );
        filterWhitelist =     (
        );
        restrictWeb = 1;
        useContentFilter = 0;
        useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
        whitelistEnabled = 0;
    }
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195761/how-to-fix-xcode-bug-web-filter-is-active I think it should be safe to ignore these

Comment: I have the test devices line in place and still getting the `WF: ` messages below that error.

Answer (score 0):

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-9966341032247898",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });

Comment: what is this ? can you please brief it ?