# How to fix xcode bug "web filter is active"?

Tags: xcode, debugging, logging

Hello I am getting this in the log and im not sure what it is and why it is logging this message also does it have any bad affect on my app ?

```
2017-02-12 20:20:21.222930 goball [760:91949] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
filterBlacklist =     (
);
filterWhitelist =     (
);
restrictWeb = 1;
useContentFilter = 0;
useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2017-02-12 20:20:21.223110 goball [760:91949] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It took me some research to figure out what's going on but what you are running into is [Safari 10's "enhanced content security policy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635505/ios-10-starting-webfilter-logging-for-process-proxy-authorization-header-rem) in action.

E.G. you might be loading your page from a remote server via `https://`, but the page itself requests images via non-encrypted `http://` URL's.

See if you can find out what image URL's are being loaded and then add the domains to your App Transport Security exceptions.

Comment: ok thanks very much for the quick response!, it must be from my amazon mobile ads sdk and admob sdk, but theres no way for me to know what ad or image will be loaded do you think this can have any impact on my app or the ads I serve ?

Comment: I don't have advertising SDK's in my own projects but if this were my problem, I'd probably reach out to both Amazon & AdMob and ask them if there are domains I can add to my app transport exceptions to get around these problems.  If you are seeing ads in your device/production versions, you should be okay.  If not, then they might be getting filtered out.

Comment: Yes ads are still showing and everything is working fine I will definitely reach out to them.  Once again thanks !