# WebFilter blocks dynamic links from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am integrating dynamic links from Firebase into my iOS app to reward new users with bonus points. In order to reward them I track the sender of the link and currently I am testing 2 scenarios:

First is when I open the Firebase dynamic link and I have the app locally installed on the iPhone. This case works perfectly fine, because the link is just redirecting me to the app and successfully prints the sender's UUID.

The second is when the app is not installed and the user has to download it from AppStore. In this case the link redirects the user to AppStore and when the app is successfully installed, I want to print the UUID of the sender. Unfortunately this is not possible due to the fact that WebFilter is blocking the Link which results to no information about the sender's UUID. In order to resolve the issue, the user has to click again on the link which trigers Scenario 1. But there is no point of using a dynamic links if we have to click twice.

Error message:

```
2021-02-15 23:56:56.453607+0100 Universal-Link-SwiftUI2.0[78267:19937175] 7.5.0 - 
[GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to 
UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

2021-02-15 23:56:57.257019+0100 Universal-Link-SwiftUI2.0[78267:19936907] WF: === Starting 
WebFilter logging for process Universal-Link-SwiftUI2.0

2021-02-15 23:56:57.257243+0100 Universal-Link-SwiftUI2.0[78267:19936907] WF: 
_userSettingsForUser mobile: {
filterBlacklist =     (
);
filterWhitelist =     (
);
restrictWeb = 1;
useContentFilter = 0;
useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
whitelistEnabled = 0;
 }
2021-02-15 23:56:57.257438+0100 Universal-Link-SwiftUI2.0[78267:19936907] WF: 
_WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

 My dynamic link object has no url
```

I found out this question: [How to fix xcode bug "web filter is active"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195761/how-to-fix-xcode-bug-web-filter-is-active)
The problem is that I am sure that the link is HTTPS, so it must be something else whcih I can not find out.

I am also allowing the ATS to load everything:[image: App Transport Security Settings]
and associated domains: [image: associated domains]

But it is still not loading. Any help will be very appreciated.

My full link is: https://makeitso.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/data?hello%3Dworld%26foo%3Dbar&isi=1312965045&ibi=com.IVANDOSE.ToDoFirebase&st=It+is+apple+pie+time&sd=Get+25%C2%A3+now&si=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Official_car_of_the_Chief_Minister_of_Gibraltar.jpeg

Comment: Same issue recently, have you found the fix yet?

Comment: Hey, Unfortunately still not, but if you find something feel free to post it here. It will be very appreciated :)

Comment: The only problem I found is that this seems to break the share link to iMessage, which turn the long link into invalid one, I workaround by combine the url into the share message/title itself instead of try sharing url separately.

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: It does works, as long as it not trying to auto resolve the URL into invalid format anymore then it will redirect to my app just fine.